# How to group xml elements using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform an existing XML structure to another XML structure.

XMLSource:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <content>
                <first>Paragraph-1</first>
                <comment>Comment-1</comment>
                <likes>like-1</likes>

                <first>Paragraph-2</first>
                <comment>Comment-2</comment>
                <likes>like-2</likes>

                <first>Paragraph-3</first>
                <comment>Comment-3</comment>

 </content>
```

Output Format Needed:

```
<content1>
 <block>
  <aaa>Paragraph-1</aaa>
  <bbb>Comment-1</bbb>
  <ccc>like-1</ccc>
 </block>
 <block>
  <aaa>Paragraph-2</aaa>
  <bbb>Comment-2</bbb>
  <ccc>like-2</ccc>
 </block>
 <block>
  <aaa>Paragraph-3</aaa>
  <bbb>Comment-3</bbb>
 </block>
</content1>
```

How this can be done using XSLT.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0 (as implemented by Saxon 9 and AltovaXML and others)? In that case you easily solve that with `<xsl:template match="content"><xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="first">...</xsl:for-each-group>`. I can post a complete example if you tell us that you can use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If the "first,comment,like" elements are not mandatory then how to implement the same, as i observe that the code is based on 'first' element occurance, if it is not mandatory one. for suppose consider the input xml<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<content><comment>Comment-1</comment><likes>like-1</likes><first>Paragraph-2</first>                
 <comment>Comment-2</comment>
<likes>like-2</likes>           
 <first>Paragraph-3</first>              
 <comment>Comment-3</comment>
</content>

Comment: And output should be like
<content1>  
<block>  
  <bbb>Comment-1</bbb>   
<ccc>like-1</ccc>  
</block>  
<block>   
<aaa>Paragraph-2</aaa>   
<bbb>Comment-2</bbb>   
<ccc>like-2</ccc>  
</block>  
<block>   
<aaa>Paragraph-3</aaa>   
<bbb>Comment-3</bbb>  
</block>
 </content1>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another XSLT 1.0 option that I prefer because everything has it's own template. I think that this makes it much easier to increase the complexity of the stylesheet than using multiple `xsl:for-each`'s.

**XML Input**

```
<content>
  <first>Paragraph-1</first>
  <likes>like-1</likes>

  <first>Paragraph-2</first>
  <comment>Comment-2</comment>
  <likes>like-2</likes>

  <first>Paragraph-3</first>
  <comment>Comment-3</comment>

  <first>Paragraph-4</first>
  <comment>Comment-4</comment>
  <likes>like-4</likes>
</content>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content">
    <content1>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </content1>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="first">
    <block>
      <aaa>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </aaa>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][name()='comment']" mode="mod"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][name()='likes']" mode="mod"/>      
    </block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment" mode="mod">
    <bbb>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </bbb>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][name()='likes']" mode="mod"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="likes" mode="mod">
    <ccc>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </ccc>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment|likes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<content1>
   <block>
      <aaa>Paragraph-1</aaa>
      <ccc>like-1</ccc>
   </block>
   <block>
      <aaa>Paragraph-2</aaa>
      <bbb>Comment-2</bbb>
      <ccc>like-2</ccc>
   </block>
   <block>
      <aaa>Paragraph-3</aaa>
      <bbb>Comment-3</bbb>
   </block>
   <block>
      <aaa>Paragraph-4</aaa>
      <bbb>Comment-4</bbb>
      <ccc>like-4</ccc>
   </block>
</content1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please observe robust XML below, and let me know if you need any more suggestions. :) I have provided more than what you had asked.

**INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <content>
      <first>Paragraph-1</first>
      <likes>like-1</likes>

      <first>Paragraph-2</first>
      <comment>Comment-2</comment>
      <likes>like-2</likes>

      <first>Paragraph-3</first>
      <comment>Comment-3</comment>

      <first>Paragraph-4</first>
      <comment>Comment-4</comment>
      <likes>like-4</likes>
    </content>
```

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content">
    <xsl:element name="content1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="first">
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(following-sibling::first)"/>
    <xsl:element name="block">
      <aaa>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </aaa>
      <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::comment[1][count(following-sibling::first) = $count]">
        <bbb>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </bbb>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::likes[1][count(following-sibling::first) = $count]">
        <ccc>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </ccc>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="comment|likes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content1>
  <block>
    <aaa>Paragraph-1</aaa>
    <ccc>like-1</ccc>
  </block>

  <block>
    <aaa>Paragraph-2</aaa>
    <bbb>Comment-2</bbb>
    <ccc>like-2</ccc>
  </block>

  <block>
    <aaa>Paragraph-3</aaa>
    <bbb>Comment-3</bbb>
  </block>

  <block>
    <aaa>Paragraph-4</aaa>
    <bbb>Comment-4</bbb>
    <ccc>like-4</ccc>
  </block>
</content1>
```

This works like gem!!!!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="start-name" select="'a'"/>
  <xsl:param name="nchars" select="3"/>
  <xsl:variable name="start-index" select="string-to-codepoints($start-name)"/>

  <xsl:template match="content">
    <content1>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="first">
        <block>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </block>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </content1>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content/*">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:element name="{string-join(for $c in 1 to $nchars return codepoints-to-string($pos - 1 + $start-index), '')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```